# Python Opencv Blend Transparent Image

Tags: python, opencv

I have a background image on which I want to overlay my transparent image. I have tried so many options so far and none has worked well. Finally, I have found the following piece of code:

```
processedImagePIL = Image.fromarray(processedImage) #since we use opencv
shuttleImagePIL = Image.fromarray(shuttleIcon) #since we use opencv
blended = Image.blend(processedImagePIL, shuttleImagePIL, alpha=0.5)
```

but even that gave me a size error

```
ValueError: images do not match
```

I don't get why the image sizes should be equal, since what I want to overlay is a small icon, expecting that to be as big as my background is kinda stupid. Is there a straightforward algorithm which is efficient in Python? Any package or implementation would do.

My icon: https://ibb.co/fecVOz

My background: https://ibb.co/chweGK

Comment: I think you might want the `Image.alpha_composite(im, dest=(0, 0), source=(0, 0))` method. You would call it as `processedImagePIL.alpha.composite(shuttleImagePIL)` . You might need to set the transparency of the icon first with something like `shuttleImagePIL.putalpha(0.5)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've got it running through OpenCV:

```
# function to overlay a transparent image on background.
def transparentOverlay(backgroundImage, overlayImage, pos=(0, 0), scale=1):
    overlayImage = cv2.resize(overlayImage, (0, 0), fx=scale, fy=scale)
    h, w, _ = overlayImage.shape  # Size of foreground
    rows, cols, _ = backgroundImage.shape  # Size of background Image
    y, x = pos[0], pos[1]  # Position of foreground/overlayImage image

    # loop over all pixels and apply the blending equation
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            if x + i >= rows or y + j >= cols:
                continue
            alpha = float(overlayImage[i][j][3] / 255.0)  # read the alpha channel
            backgroundImage[x + i][y + j] = alpha * overlayImage[i][j][:3] + (1 - alpha) * backgroundImage[x + i][y + j]
    return backgroundImage
```

And then used as follows:

```
# Overlay transparent images at desired postion(x,y) and Scale.
result = transparentOverlay(processedImage, shuttleIcon, tuple(trackedCenterPoint), 0.7)
```

seemed to have solved my problems.